# Eclipse IDE add new LaunchGroup mode as a developer

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

Am trying to add new launch mode here:
[image: Launch mode list]

For example I want new mode called "Load".
I found this extention point: `org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchGroups`, which eventually define the launchGroup interface.
I have 2 question:

1. I found this on internet:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchGroups">
    <launchGroup
        id="com.example.ExampleLaunchGroupId"
        mode="run"
        label="Run"
        image="icons\run.png"
        bannerImage="icons\runBanner.png">
    </launchGroup>
</extension>
```

"In the above example, the launch group will consist of all launch configurations with no category that support run mode. "
why this will make run mode will disappear?

2. I added this to my code

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchGroups">
    <launchGroup
        bannerImage="icons/ex.png"
        id="com.ExampleLaunchGroupId"
        image="icons/ex.png"
        label="Load only"
        mode="load">
    </launchGroup>
</extension>
```

in a result the new mode "Load" is added to the "Launch mode" list but the run mode disappeared, why? and how to add the a new mode without delete another one?
thanks

Comment: @greg-449 The sub-dialog that is shown when in a _Launch Group_ you click on _Add..._ or _Edit..._

Comment: `mode="load"` makes only sense when you have specified such a mode via the [`org.eclipse.debug.core.launchModes` extension point](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_debug_core_launchModes.html). The [documentation of the `org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchGroups` can be found in the help here](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_debug_ui_launchGroups.html). Look also into the code of Eclipse (`run` and `debug` by Platform or `profile` by EclEmma).

Comment: I added the new mode to org.eclipse.debug.core.launchMode as well and I can use this mode and everything works fine, but I don’t understand why the “Run” mode disappeared from the Launch mode list.. @howlger

Comment: And sorry if I don’t understand the documentation of launchGroups extension point but the example in this link isn’t clear why the run mode will be disappeared ..@howlger

Comment: I don't know why the "Run" mode disappeared when `load` was not specified. You'd probably have to look into the [code of Eclipse](https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.debug) for that if you really want to know.

Comment: That dialog is `org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.groups.GroupLaunchConfigurationSelectionDialog`. You could start there are try and debug what is going on.